# Pagination in express app

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I have an array of json objects that is produced by a function when my express app is running. If there is only one object then it gets rendered by the following jade view

```
p You searched for '#{prop}'
  h2 Result
    if response
      -var numResults = response.hits.total
      #numResults
      p Number of hits #{numResults}
        -for (var i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
          pre= JSON.stringify(response.hits.hits[i], null, ' ')
        -}
    else
      p No Matches
```

If there are more than two objects to render though, they are all currently rendered one after the one down the page. I would prefer just to render one object, and have a `prev` and `next` button underneath it that would allow the user to cycle through the other objects, i.e. only one object rendered at a time in the same place in the page. What is the best way to tackle this?

If I follow an approach like below, then I can toggle visibility but rather than show all or nothing, I'd like to cycle through the items, i.e. default displays item 1, click to show only item 2, again for item 3 etc.

```
script.
  function toggledisplay(elementID)
    {
      (function(style) {
        style.display = style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
      })(document.getElementById(elementID).style);
    }


a(href="#" title="Show Tags" onClick="toggledisplay('changethis');") Show All Tags
ul(class="subforums" id="changethis" style="overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ")
  li Item 1
  li Item 2
  li Item 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Render everything (all results), but show only one (the first), hide the others with css.

Add a click listener to the buttons **prev** and **next** to toggle the visibility for the results.